# check for condition in site.master page

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, master-pages

I have a site.master page in an asp application which contains a div menu and it looks like this.

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="first"><a href="sample.aspx">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="managerserviceshome.aspx">manager services</a></li>
        <li><a href ="employeeservicehome.aspx">employee services</a></li>
        <li><a href="myprojectshomepage.aspx">my projects</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

What i want is that the manager services portion should be visible only if a particular employee has his 'Is_Manager' field set to True in the database. For the rest this tag should be invisible. How do I achieve this?? How do i check for this contidion over here in this site.master page? please help.

Comment: can you post menu code ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do it inside of the mark up. In the code behind on page load, set the Is_Manager flag and look it up from the database. Then, in the markup, do this:

```
<% if(Is_Manager){%>
 <li><a href="ManagerServicesHome.aspx">Manager Services</a></li>
<%}%>
```

Comment: Yes - this is the way to go. One can use protected/public method/property in place of Is_Manager flag - in the method/property body, one may write the code that will do necessary lookup to decide if current user is manager or not.

Answer (score 0):

Given what you've provided so far ...

in the cs file for the master:

```
protected bool IsVisible;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
  IsVisible = (bool)Session["isVisible"];
}
```

in the aspx for the master page

```
<style>
  .manager { visibility = <%= (IsVisible) ? "visible" : "hidden" %>;}
</style>

<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="first"><a href="sample.aspx">home</a></li>
        <li class="manager"><a href="managerserviceshome.aspx">manager services</a></li>
        <li><a href ="employeeservicehome.aspx">employee services</a></li>
        <li><a href="myprojectshomepage.aspx">my projects</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: If you set a style, anyone can easily remove it from F12... So It's a "little bit" dangerous.

Comment: That is true of _everything_ in the DOM tho???

Comment: Yeah, but here the man talks about "ManagerServicesHome.aspx", so probably an admin view. I think It's Better to prevent sending the <a> tag with href to the client from the server and prevent the possibility to easily access to It simply removing a css.